# How can I convert number to hh:mm:ss?

Tags: r, time

I have a column in a dataframe that is the number of seconds past midnight. How would I got about converting that number to a time displayed as hh:mm:ss? For instance:

| hrsecs |
| --- |
| 1563 |
| 13088 |
| 14309 |

becomes

| Time |
| --- |
| 00:26:03 |
| 03:38:08 |
| 03:58:29 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the seconds to period (`seconds_to_period`) and use `hms` from `hms` package

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
   transmute(Time = hms::hms(seconds_to_period(hrsecs)))
```

-output

```
df1
  Time
1 00:26:03
2 03:38:08
3 03:58:29
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(hrsecs = c(1563L, 13088L, 14309L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) character output** Convert to POSIXct and then format.  No packages are used.

```
x <- c(1563, 13088, 14309)
tt <- format(as.POSIXct("1970-01-01") + x, "%T"); tt
## [1] "00:26:03" "03:38:08" "03:58:29"
```

or

```
tt <- format(structure(x, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), "%T")
tt
## [1] "00:26:03" "03:38:08" "03:58:29"
```

**2) times class output** If you want to be able to manipulate the times then this will express them internally as fractions of a day but render them as times.

```
library(chron)
times(tt)
## [1] 00:26:03 03:38:08 03:58:29
```